# Find all workflows with a certain permission setting

Tags: 2010, permissions, site-collection, web-application

I have a workflow which just got broken by a network administrator changing some active directory settings for a certain group. I was able to fix the workflow once the problem had been found but there are a large number of workflows on the site and I don't know if the same problem might exist elsewhere (I am new to the system).

Is there a way to search all workflows in a web application or site collection for actions where permissions are set for a certain user/group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

You would probably need to write some custom code in powershell or a c# console app to recursively explore your farm and check [SPList.WorkflowAssociations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.workflowassociations.aspx) for your workflow.

I'm not sure I would try even searching by permission because they could be set in so many different places: items, list, library, site, etc.